# How in Unity to create a water level in a bottle?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello everyone There is such a problem - I have a bottle sprite and a sprite showing the water level in this bottle. But, as you understand, if you start rotating the bottle, the level will remain the same. How to make the water rotate realistically? (was always downstairs)
As far as I understand, you probably need a shader, but I'm not strong at all.

I tried to make water in small circles with physics, but it works unstable and the balls periodically slip through the wall.

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb8QI.png)
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcTko.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you don't care about liquid sloshing and the volume staying consistent you can use a simple sprite mask.

[image: image of a cola bottle that rotates while keeping the liquid level]

[image: view of the liquid game object and components]

Note that the box collider isn't necessary, it was just added to illustrate the underlying sprite size.

[image: view of the bottle game object and components]

Comment: It works! Thanks. But if it is necessary to move the bottle, the mask will be a child object and will move behind the bottle. Is there another way?

Comment: Movement is indeed a bit more tricky. You have to make a choice: either keep it in this arrangement and move the `Liquid`, which also moves the `Bottle` or you can swap the hierarchy and attach the `Liquid` to the `Bottle`. In the latter configuration you would have to counter rotate the `Liquid`. Both variants are viable you just need to pick the one that you like best and is easier to program for you.